# Is it possible to use the "slideUp Bar" on tvOs

Tags: tvos, apple-tv

I am still experimenting with the new tvOs and was wondering whether apple let's use there slideUp bar or HUD or whatever name they gave this area at the bottom of the screen. (this one -> https://developer.apple.com/tvos/human-interface-guidelines/visual-design/images/visual-design-light-bg.png)

Unfortunately I couldn't find anything regarding this in the docs.

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing this, it look like it is a private API (same as the HUD on iOS). You should be able to recreate this though by using a separate UIView that captures the touchpad events.